# In scala 2.13.x, is there a way to loop over the values of a Enumeration where Value is a String?

Tags: scala

I have an enumeration like this:

```
object UserType extends Enumeration {
   type UserType = String
   val member = "member"
   val admin = "admin"
}
```

Is there a way to get all the values of the Enumeration so it returns:

```
val userTypes: Set[String] = UserType.values.toSet
```

For some reason `UserType.values` returns of type UserType.Value or something, not a string.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe you may want to give it a look to [**Enumeratum**](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum).

Comment: [Enumeration in Scala](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumeration-in-scala/) seems to have all the example code you might need for the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

If you want use Enumeration need set `Value` to your type:

```
type UserType = Value
```

And then define variable as:

```
val admin = Value("admin")
```

Otherwise, you don't use a Enumeration.

---

For get list of all values:

```
UserType.values.toList
```